# Is it possible to set custom attributes of SVG objects as number and not as string?

Tags: javascript, svg, attributes, d3.js

I am assigning artificial attributes to a SVG-G element (SVG group object). I move the group with its content with SVG transformations and I store the x/y coordinates of the group and its width/height in those attributes.

I am using the D3 Javascript library and the call :

```
embeddedElemContainer = nodeBoxContainer.append('svg:g')
    .attr('x', x)
    .attr('y', y)
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
```

results in following  object :

```
<g transform="translate(13.585786437626904,31.585786437626904)" x="13.585786437626904" y="31.585786437626904" width="43.00000000000001" height="0"></g>
```

This is Ok, the only ting bothering me is the fact, that the attribute values are stored as string. If I want to use them for some computation, I am forced to cast.

```
parseInt(@embeddedElemContainer.attr('x'))
```

Is there a way to store those values directly as integer/double ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The normal approach in D3 is to have lists of data that are bound to nodes. See the [data portion of the Selection API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data).  D3 puts this in the `__data__` property of the DOM nodes that it creates/modifies. Internally D3 pulls out that property and passes it as a parameter to various functions, but you can certainly access it yourself directly.

It's also possible to associate an arbitrary data structure to a **single** node via the [Datum method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-datum).

Without the rest of the context it's hard to say, but below is a modified version of what I think you are trying to do:

```
var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 400).attr("height", 300);

var groupData = {x: 100, y:100, height: 50, width: 50, theanswer : 42, thecolor: "blue", somedouble: 45.1651654 };

var embeddedElemContainer = vis.append('svg:g')
    .datum( groupData )
    .attr( 'id', 'mygroup' )
    .attr( 'x', function(d) { return d.x; } )
    .attr( 'y', function(d) { return d.y; } )
    .attr( 'height', function(d) { return d.height; } )
    .attr( 'width', function(d) { return d.width; } )

// the regular DOM way:
console.log(document.getElementById('mygroup').__data__)

// the D3 way:
console.log( d3.select('#mygroup').datum() );
```

Both `console.log` statements output:

```
height: 50
somedouble: 45.1651654
theanswer: 42
thecolor: "blue"
width: 50
x: 100
y: 100
```

Comment: OH! Many thanks for your great explanation. I have to read more about the bounding data/attributes to elements in D3. Never thought about to use this functionality for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could override d3's `attr` function to sniff out numbers and do the `parseInt` for you. That might present compatibility problems later, so maybe it would be better to create a new `attrInt` function, for example:

```
d3.selection.prototype.attrInt = function(name, value) {
  if(arguments.length == 1) {
    return parseInt(this.attr(name));
  } else {
    return this.attr(name, value);
  }
};
```

Disclaimer: I don't have experience with d3 so I'm not sure if that is the correct prototype to attach to; I just picked that up from glancing at the source. :)

Comment: While this might work, I think D3 has a cleaner built-in approach for this. See my answer.