# D3 custom attributes not being selected

Tags: d3.js

I currently have a hexagonal grid that is generated through looping through (thus the `i` and the `j`) and appending `<polygon>` as the following (which is nested inside a `<svg>`):

```
d3.select("g").append("polygon").attr("points", grid[i][j]).attr("style", "fill:#fff;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1;").attr("posX", j).attr("posY", i);
```

such that each `<polygon>` has the custom attributes of `posX` and `posY`.

When I try to select a given hexagon and attempt to 'highlight' the location, such as below:

```
d3.select("polygon[posX='1'][posY='1']").attr("style", "fill:#999;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1;");
```

it simply doesn't work and throws no errors.  I can post more code if necessary.

Here is the broader click function:

```
$("polygon").click(function () {
    var x = d3.select(this).attr("posX");
    var y = d3.select(this).attr("posY");
    d3.select(this).attr("style", "fill:#333;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1;");
    $("#cords").text(x + "," + y);

    //neighbors
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        var ret = getNeighbor("ooq", i, x, y);
        console.log(ret);
        //d3.select("polygon[posX='" + ret[0] + "']").attr("style", "fill:#111;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1;");
        d3.select("polygon[posX='1'][posY='1']").attr("style", "fill:#999;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1;");
    }
});
```

I attempted a solution with these to no avail:

- [D3 Equivalent to jQuery Attribute selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043279/d3-equivalent-to-jquery-attribute-selector)
- [d3.select by attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414980/d3-select-by-attribute-value)
- [Is it possible to set custom attributes of SVG objects as number and not as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081244/is-it-possible-to-set-custom-attributes-of-svg-objects-as-number-and-not-as-stri)

If I simply missed an important point in one of those references, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rearranged the looping to have each `<polygon>` be contained within a `<g>` tag, where I put the `posX` and `posY` attributes, instead.  Through the mouseenter event, I select `this` using D3 on the polygon, step up to its parent, then work from there.  jQuery is able to see the attributes on the `<g>` so this workaround seemed to accommodate my needs.

Comment: This worked also for me. I wrapped all my elements and stored the custom attributes to the partent `<g>` tag. I was able to wrap a set of elements (rect in my case) by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43425135/1423806